# Problems with formatting a bar chart

Tags: formatting, plotting

I am trying to create a financial dashboard using *Mathematica*. I am having trouble formatting the axes ticks to show whole numbers. Further, when I hover over one of the chart elements, it is displayed in scientific notation. I have attached the code and an image.

```
Manipulate[
  sql = StringJoin[
    "select Right(Period,2) as [Period], SUM(Revenue) as [Revenue] ", 
    " from PRSummaryCMF where Month >=  ", ToString[a], 
    " and Year =  ", ToString[b], " group by Period order by Period"];
  n = SQLExecute[conn, sql];
  BarChart[n[[All, 2]], 
    ChartLabels -> {n[[All, 1]]}, 
    ChartStyle -> "Pastel" , 
    BarSpacing -> Automatic], 
  {{b, 2010, "Year"}, {2010, 2011, 2012, 2013}, ControlType -> Setter}, 
  {{a, "01", "Period"}, 
    {"01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12"}, 
    ControlType -> Setter,  Appearance -> "Labeled"},
  ContentSize -> 500]
```

[image: Output Image]

Comment: Take a look here http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/OutputFormatsForNumbers.html

Answer (score 2):

My attempt:

```
n = Table[{x , x  RandomReal[] 10^6}, {x, 1, 12}];
BarChart[n[[All, 2]],
 LabelingFunction -> (AccountingForm[#] &),
 Frame -> True,
 FrameTicks -> {{Table[{x, AccountingForm[x], {.01, 0}}, {x, 10^5, 
      10^7, 10^6}], None}, {None, None}},
 ChartLabels -> Placed[n[[All, 1]], {{0.5, 0}, {0, 2}}] ,
 ChartStyle -> "Pastel",
 BarSpacing -> Automatic]
```

[image: a bar chart]

But I think it should be easier than this somehow…